# How to get url parameters from controller in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

so, in my `app.js` :

```
.state('app.packages', {
  url: "/packages/:packagesId",
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/packages.html",
      controller: function ($stateParams) {
        console.log($stateParams);
      }
    }
   }
})
```

in browser console, it showing this :

`Object {packagesId: "25242039"}`

How do i access the $stateParams that hold the value of `packagesId` inside `controller.js`?

Currently doing it like this, but it is not working...

```
.controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope,$stateParams) {
  $scope.getId = function(){
    return $scope = $stateParams.packagesId ;
 };
})
```

Comment: Have you referenced the right controller in your state ? (the snippet you show us still has `controller: function ($stateParams) {console.log($stateParams);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I don't understand why you want to assign the id to the scope `return $scope = $stateParams.packagesId;`

Secondly, you have a controller PlaylistCtrl, so you need to set it for router state.

```
 // you may try simple view first
.state('app.packages', {
  url: "/packages/:packagesId",
  templateUrl: "templates/packages.html",
  controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
```

Comment: owh..thanx a lot ! i just dont realize that i assign it to wrong controller. It should be `PlaylistCtrl` and not `PlaylistsCtrl`